# Telling a custom delegate when to call a method

Tags: objective-c, ios, class, delegates

I've created a custom class with various methods in [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) and I've also added delegate methods to that class that can be called from another class that imports my custom class. In particular I'm working with iOS. Here's a small sample of both my header (.h) and implementation (.m) files:

```
//iCloud.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol iCloudDelegate;
@class iCloud;

@interface iCloud : NSObject {
    __weak id<iCloudDelegate> delegate_;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <iCloudDelegate> delegate;

//Methods (abridged for StackOverflow)
+ (void)checkCloudAvailability;

@end

@class iCloud;
@protocol iCloudDelegate <NSObject>
//Methods (abridged for StackOverflow)
@optional
- (void)documentWasSaved;
@required
- (void)iCloudAvailable:(BOOL)status;
@end
```

And part of my implementation (.m):

```
#import "iCloud.h"
@implementation iCloud
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)documentWasSaved {
    [[self delegate] documentWasSaved];
}

-(void)iCloudAvailable:(BOOL)status {
    [[self delegate] iCloudAvailable:status];
}

+ (void)checkCloudAvailability {
NSLog(@"Checking iCloud availablity...");
NSURL *returnedURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

if (returnedURL){
    NSLog(@"iCloud is available");
} else {
    NSLog(@"iCloud not available. ☹");
}
}
```

I've looked through numerous tutorials, SO postings, sample code, and more to try to figure out **how to tell the delegate WHEN to call the delegate methods**, but I haven't been able to find anything. Most postings show that the implementation should add the delegate (using the `<DelegateName>` syntax), *however* my custom class implementation is not where I want to use the delegate (it's in another class where the delegate is NOT being created in).

As you can see in the sample code above, I've added the delegate methods (in the implementation) but as far as I'm aware all this will do is call the delegate methods in the other classes that use it. If this is correct, then how do I get the delegate to call those methods (say from my `checkCloudAvailability` class which is not one of the delegate methods)? Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
+ (void)checkCloudAvailability
    if (returnedURL){
      [[self delegate] iCloudAvailable:YES]; 
    ...
}
```

When I try to use the `[[self delegate] methodName];` line I get the following error, and Xcode pretends like it doesn't know what I'm talking about anymore: [image]

Why is this happening? Why can't I tell the delegate *when* to call the delegate methods? This works fine inside of the delegate methods, but why not in the class in which it is being implemented?

Thoughts, ideas, links, tutorials, code, or help of any kind will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says that it cannot find a method `delegate` is not available in the context of a *class method* (i.e. one denoted with a `+` sign). This may look confusing, because `self` inside a class method does not correspond to an instance, but to a class; the property `delegate`, on the other hand, belongs to an instance, meaning that it is not available.

To address this, you should either make `checkCloudAvailability` an instance method, or rewrite it as follows:

```
+(void)checkCloudAvailabilityWithDelegate:(id<iCloudDelegate>)delegate {
    ...
}
```

Comment: In the latter case, I think it would be easier if he'd just create a class method `checkCloudAvailability` that would return whether or not iCloud is available. Delegation isn't really necessary in this case.

Comment: @Scott I agree - the only reason I see to use a `delegate` there is to maintain consistency with something that has access to a `delegate`. For example, if several *instance* methods could potentially reuse this *class* method, they could share the code that checks if the `@optional` method is implemented by passing a delegate to the class method.

Comment: Yes you are both right, this could be much simpler, I agree. I've used your comments here to change my design pattern here and it works beautifully. Also, note that the method in the question was just an example.

Answer (score 2):

You call **class** method +(void)checkCloudAvailability.
"self" in class methods means class object, not instance object.
But delegate variable declared for instance object.

Answer (score 0):

Look it's a class method. I'll also use a property instead of a instance variable:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<iCloudDelegate> delegate;
@synthesize delegate = delegate_;
```

Answer (score -1):

When you use the '+' annotation before a function call, it becomes a static method. Within a static method, you cannot call 'self'

Comment: You **can** call `self`, it just denotes a different thing (a class, rather than an instance). I think this was the ultimate source of the OP's confusion.

Comment: You're mixing your nomenclature. For one thing, an Objective-C method is not the same thing as a function, and there's no such thing as a static method in Objective-C. Methods prefixed with a `+` are class methods, not static methods.